# Can we have mulitple shards in source MongoDB and no shards or less shards in backup db

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, backup, sharding

i don't want to create multiple shards in backup db as it would be waste of resources instead can we just have single db which will be combination of multiple shards from source.

Comment: General idea about having multiple shards backup is that (i) they are small sized faster backups, and (ii) the backups can be run in parallel.

Comment: what i want to do is to replicate those shards into less no of shards. Ex. Source has 4 shards but i want to replicate all 4 shards into 2 shards.

Comment: can we replicate sharded mongo db into unsharded one